# How can I select specific elements within similar groups of three?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple web page running on ESP8266, written in HTML with CSS, bootstrap ans some javascript. On this page there is 12 div's, each with a " 3 position" nav-pills. Clicking on each of them sends corresponding value to the server(ESP8266). This part works great. When user loads this page, web browser sends GET request to obtain those values back and display them on the web page by changing ( "highliting" ) corresponding nav-item in each nav-pills.. Getting response from server works but i don't know hot to "get access" to each nav-pills class and change their nav-item . This is the code im talking about :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.nav-pills li:nth-child(1) a').tab('show'); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 w-100 p-2" style="">
      <div class="card text-center shadow-none">
        <div class="card-header p-1">
          <h2 class="text-center shadow"><b class="text-center">Okno 1</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body p-1">
          <a class="btn btn-primary m-1" style="color: white;" id="1" value="open" ><b>OTWÓRZ</b></a><a class="btn btn-primary m-1" style="color: white;" id="1" value="close" ><b>ZAMKNIJ</b></a><a class="btn btn-primary m-1" style="color: white;" id="1" value="stop" ><b>STOP</b><br></a> </div>
        <div class="card-body p-1">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%">!!!</div>
          </div>
          <h4 class="pt-2 shadow-none">Tryb pracy<br></h4>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills m-0 text-center w-100" style="">
           <li class="nav-item" id="1" value="czas"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Czas</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" id="1" value="reczny"> <a href="" class="nav-link"  data-toggle="pill">Ręczny</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" id="1" value="swiatlo"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Światło</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 p-2 w-100" style="">
      <div class="card text-center shadow-none">
        <div class="card-header p-1">
          <h2 class="text-center shadow"><b class="text-center">Okno 2</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body p-1">
          <a class="btn btn-primary m-1" style="color: white;" id="2" value="open" ><b>OTWÓRZ</b></a><a class="btn btn-primary m-1" style="color: white;" id="2" value="close" ><b>ZAMKNIJ</b></a><a class="btn btn-primary m-1" style="color: white;" id="2" value="stop" ><b>STOP</b><br></a> </div>
        <div class="card-body p-1">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%">!!!</div>
          </div>
          <h4 class="pt-2">Tryb pracy<br></h4>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills m-0 text-center w-100" style="">
            <li class="nav-item" id="2" value="czas"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Czas</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" id="2" value="reczny"> <a href="" class="nav-link"  data-toggle="pill">Ręczny</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" id="2" value="swiatlo"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Światło</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This works ok for one nav-pill bar but how can i iterate thru all 12 of them and be able to set their nav-item individually ? In each of those 12 nav-pills, there should be only one item active (highlighted)...

[Page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMNZO.png)

I've added a screenshot of this page to visualise how this looks like. Each nav-pills below "Tryb pracy" works as a mode selector for each card.

Comment: Why are you using `id="1"` on all? This makes the id attribute completely useless. Use id-s with name part and index, like `pill-1`, `pill-2` and so on. Then you can access each individually, and use `not` selector to access all others in one shot.

Comment: There is 12 "sets" like that. Each set with id="1", id="2"... id="12". Im using the same id for each group of 3 nav-items because im passing it as an argument to the server, so the server knows which group was clicked and stores this id with coresponding value in and array of 12 elements ( where id is an index ). Then, when requested ( on page load ), server sends this array as "XML format", and im iterating thru this response to get each value. This part works well and this was the simplest solution i came up with...

Comment: in that case, I would have a containing div with the id, otherwise it breaks the HTML validitiy

Comment: The answer depends on the triggering event context. Please 1) fix your ID issue to be valid (use IDs at a higher level and use classes therein), and 2) show more of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestions. I can change those id's but im not that much concerned about HTML validity as this page won't be public - it's part of a small home automation project, accesible only from local network at my own house...
I'm just truin to figure out how ( if possible at all) to combine :
document.getElementsByClassName("nav-pills")[index]) 
with
 $('.nav-pills li:nth-child(1) a').tab('show');
Or have any other solution to acces each nav-pill and change their active( highlighted ) pill individually....

Comment: You should be concerned by the HTML validity whether the application is public or not, because it eases its maintability and you're less likely to shoot yourself in the foot. You may not have an error due to that right now, but when the app will grow you won't know why you have that error. Sometimes you'll have code that just won't work and will have no error at all, just because you tried to get the id's but you forgot you did that thing 2 years ago. 
The advised way of doing what you're doing is to use "data-id" instead of "id", and get that attribute, much cleaner and understandable.

Comment: @Zakaria Sahmane, Thank you for your suggestion.
Yes, I was aware of possible future problems, especially with browser compatibility. But i was trying to use knowledge ( poor one, in terms of web code .. ) that i have at this time :) And first get this part working, before i go to clean up the code...
I wasn't aware of data-id attr... can you plese correct me if I'm wrong :
Change all ids to unique ones, then add data-id attributes with the same value for each group of elements that i want to pass to server? Will that be valid? Or data-id has to be unique too?

Comment: @ZetKa The data attribute allows you to attach data to any html element. "data-id" is just an example, you can use "data-index" or "data-whatever-index-i-want", basically you can put the data attribute behind the name of any data you need to attach to a particular element. The values don't have to be unique, it depends on your database, structure you want etc. You can have as many "data-id" as you want with the same value. When you retrieve them you'll get all of them and use them as you like. You're free to use the data-* attribute as you like, because it is meant to store data.

Comment: @Zakaria Sahmane, Thank you so much for excellent explanation and a good idea :) I have allready changed all ids to unique, and added "data-ids" - code on both sides ( client and server ) works like a charm ( so far... ;) )

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it shows how to apply the javascript event only to one specific nav-pill

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.nav-item').mouseover(function() {
     $(this).addClass('highlight');
  });
  
  $('.nav-item').mouseout(function() {
     $(this).removeClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills m-0 text-center w-100" style="">
    <li class="nav-item" id="pill-1" value="czas"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Czas</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="pill-2" value="reczny"> <a href="" class="nav-link"  data-toggle="pill">Ręczny</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="pill-3" value="swiatlo"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Światło</a> </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding another class to each class "nav-pills" , like so:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills m-0 text-center w-100 mode-1" style="">
           <li class="nav-item" id="1" value="czas"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Czas</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" id="1" value="reczny"> <a href="" class="nav-link"  data-toggle="pill">Ręczny</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" id="1" value="swiatlo"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Światło</a> </li>
          </ul>
<ul class="nav nav-pills m-0 text-center w-100 mode-2" style="">
           <li class="nav-item" id="1" value="czas"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Czas</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" id="1" value="reczny"> <a href="" class="nav-link"  data-toggle="pill">Ręczny</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item" id="1" value="swiatlo"> <a href=""  class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">Światło</a> </li>
          </ul>
```

Then i can iterate in for() loop :

```
var index;
var ilosc_okien = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("tryb").length; 
 for (index = 0; count < ilosc_okien; count++) {
       if (request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('tryb')[index].childNodes[0].nodeValue === "czas") {
      $('.mode-' +[index+1]+' li:nth-child(1) a').tab('show');
       }// end if == czas

        if (request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('tryb')[index].childNodes[0].nodeValue === "reczny") {
    $('.mode-' +[index+1]+' li:nth-child(2) a').tab('show');
       }// end if == reczny

       if (request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('tryb')[index].childNodes[0].nodeValue === "swiatlo") {
    $('.mode-' +[index+1]+' li:nth-child(3) a').tab('show');
       }// end if == swiatlo
     }// end for loop
```

Maybe it's not pretty but gets the job done. Thank you all :)